# NodeJS + socket.io: Server not recieving emitted messages

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm setting up a simple project using NodeJS and socket.io (and Express). My app.js looks like:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 8003;
var __root = '/voidwalker/';
console.log('Listening on port: ' + port);

// Settings //
app.set('views', __dirname + '/tpl');
app.set('view engine', "jade");
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
app.use(__root, express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Pages //
app.get(__root, function(req, res) {
    res.render('voidwalker');
});

// Socket.io //
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('message', {message: 'Welcome to the chat!'});
    socket.on('send', function(data) {
        console.log('TEST', data);
        io.sockets.emit('message', data);
    });
});
```

And my client-side js looks like:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://node.domain.com:8003/voidwalker/');
    if ( settings.debug ) console.debug('Loaded socket.io', socket);

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log('data recieved')
        console.log(data);
    });

    console.log(socket.emit('send', {'test': 'io.sockets.emit'}));
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work at all. Here is a copy of my log after a single client connected:

```
[webadmin@server ~]$ node /var/www/node/apps/voidwalker/app.js
Listening on port: 8003
   info  - socket.io started
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized 4F7Zocz71RaQv7w5WOVg
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/4F7Zocz71RaQv7w5WOVg
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client 4F7Zocz71RaQv7w5WOVg
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"message","args":[{"message":"Welcome to the chat!"}]}
```

And my developer console returns this:

```
Loaded socket.io: SocketNamespace {socket: Socket, name: "/voidwalker/", flags: Object, json: Flag, ackPackets: 0…}
```

I'm expecting to see the return value of `console.log('TEST', data);` in my CLI when a client connects but it never shows up.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the browser console? And what is the debugging output in the browser? You already added some statements to track what is going on at browser side, so share them with us please.

Comment: I added the content of my developer console ;) There are no error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about

```
var socket = io.connect('http://node.domain.com:8003/voidwalker/');
```

?

Only because you bind some middleware to this path, I would not expect socket.io to listen there too. Actually its [default endpoint is `/socket.io`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO#server)(see the `endpoint` option), which would not fit to the endpoint you are trying to connect to. I would give

```
var socket = io.connect('http://node.domain.com:8003/');
```

a try. The client uses [`socket.io` as default endpoint](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO#client) so this should fit together then.

Comment: It seemed to work! The problem was that the entire project is located in a subdirectory of my root (`/voidwalker`), so I thought I had to specify it.